# Subpage of website cannot be edited in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, training-certification

I seem to have a weird problem with my dummy website.  I am learning about Sitecore via their e-learning tutorials, and currently have a front page with sub page.  The problem is with the sub page, 
it cannot be edited in the experience editor. The Sitecore ribbon is not available within the sub page and if I try to open the page In edit mode, Sitecore redirects me to a blank page with the text “Default page”..

I am pretty lost on where I should look or how I should debug the situation. I am not quite sure I understand why I am able to preview the page, but not see the ribbon or somehow edit the content within Sitecore? [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots where ribbon is not available to your original question

Comment: Screenshot added...

Comment: Have you by any chance removed default Home item? Could you make screenshot of your content tree under /sitecore/content in Content Editor. Could you also make a screenshot of presentation details for this page and also for page where this is working? Similarly to this one: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/creating_and_editing_items/editing/edit_the_layout_of_an_item in chapter 'Edit the layout details of an item' and section 3.

Comment: I added the images climb Mount is the problem

Comment: When you're in the Edit mode on the home page, are you able to use the Navigation Bar (the breadcrumb-looking nav) to get to the Climb Mount...item? If so, are you able to edit the item then?

Comment: Maybe include the cshtml file if you're creating that as part of an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this issue on occasion and have run into some scenarios which may cause this.  In general, what seems to cause the problem is if you have certain special characters as content within the fields you are trying to edit with the Experience Editor.  I have seen it involve help text of all things.  I wrote about it in this blog...

https://sabor413blog.wordpress.com/2018/01/22/using-double-quotes-in-sitecore-fields-short-description-help-text-field/

I wrote another blog recently referencing a situation with special characters which caused saving problems with components on Sitecore

https://sabor413blog.wordpress.com/2018/03/10/experience-editor-error-involving-special-characters-in-sitecore-8-1-8-2/

So in short I think the underlying cause is some bad HTML or content in one of your data fields, rendering parameter fields or rich text fields...

Comment: That is indeed not a bad answer.... but I have so far only commented all parts who contain some sort of `@html.sitecore().field()`... without that is it a plain cshtml page.

Comment: If this site is from the training class, it may be the page which is not designed to be editable in Sitecore.  I know that some of the instructions will involve creating components from this page and then afterwards you are able to edit the page successfully in Sitecore.  Unfortunately the part you commented out (i.e. @html.sitecore.field()) are the parts which make the page editable in Sitecore.  I wish I could take a closer look at your environment, I bet I would be able to figure out what is going on, I used to teach the class.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore will never redirect to other item if you open any item with edit mode. Please check the network flow. You might get idea whether it is redirecting or not. Also please check logs, you might get some idea from there as well.

If the specific item doesn't have any layout then it will prompt you that item doesn't have any layout and if there is any exception on page then edit mode will show that exception.

In edit mode redirection is only possible if it is programed.